# Deploy and install a SharePoint Hosted Add-in to all site collections (sites and subsites) at once in SharePoint Online(Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-addin, deployment, upgrade

I have many site collections that use a SharePoint Add-in common for most of the pages in sites and subsites.

Each time when I create a new version of add-in and upload in appcatalog, I have to manually go to all the sites and follow steps - s`ite contents> select add-in > click on upgrade > Get it` .

Is there anyway such that if I upload new version of an app it should automatically upgraded in all the sites?

Also if new app id added to appcatalog, can it be added to all sites , even trust it should also be taken care for itself.

I have tried below link from which I was able to only deploy the Add-in but not install it.

> [Tenancies and deployment scopes for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896(v=office.15).aspx#AppScope)

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Add-in inside the App Catalog itself you will have access to the Add-in's Deployment options. You have to actually install it in the App Catalog, not just upload it.

Here's a blog that walks through the process.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/03/04/sharepoint-2013-app-deployment-through-app-stapling/

Comment: Hi Omer,

This adds app only to the site contents. To  add it as webpart to the page, we have to trust it again by going to individual sites manually.